# Angular 2 app slow to load

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have been reading how System JS is slow in loading an angular 2 apps dependencies, but I was wondering if there was a way to speed this up. I have a small app I started at [www.foxridgesc.com](http://www.foxridgesc.com)

If you notice, based on the angular seed app, it takes a bit to load the first time. I have put my scripts at the bottom etc, but still very slow. Any ideas how to speed things up?

my code is here. https://github.com/judsonmusic/foxridgesc

Comment: Have you minified your scripts before deploying? That often helps

Comment: Not yet, but not even clear on what to minify since everything is pointing to node modules stuff etc. Tons of dependencies with angular 2.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with angular 2 but the idea is to minify all of the external scripts together. And yes, angular 2 kinda bloaty

Comment: @JudsonTerrell I have an angular2 app and its always 4 seconds on website. Did you manage to get yours faster? if so how?